# Internet Explorer Audio Disable

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

how do I disable Internet Explorer webpage audio using VBScript?

I've been trying to make a script that runs windows internet explorer on specific link in the background invisible but, I don't know how to turn off the audio while its invisible.
EXTRA INFORMATION: (MY SCRIPT)

```
   Visible = 0 'it won't show

    Set objExplorer = WScript.CreateObject _
    ("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
    objExplorer.Navigate "www.youtube.com"

    'Determines if the window is visible or not
    objExplorer.Visible = 0

    im trying to add somewhere a thing that makes it mutes the window 

    Sub IE_onQuit()
    Wscript.Quit
    End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe if you post your script somebody will find it easier to help you to find the error ;)

Comment: um its simple but okay